# Case insensitive common filter in Laravel 5 datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable

Using datatables in laravel 5 as:

```
return Datatables::of($email_details)
                        ->filterColumn('from_name', 'from_lname', 'subject', 'date')
                        ->make(true);
```

My data is like that:

```
ABC XYZ subject1 22-02-2016
abc XYZ subject1 22-02-2016
FFF XYZ subject1 22-02-2016
```

when I am going to filter : abc , it exactly matches.
I want two records : ABC, abc.

is there changes in JS?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and figured it out by debugging the code.

What I did to solve the issue:

- browse to {laravelProjectDir}\vendor\yajra\laravel-datatables-oracle\src\config\
- copy the file *config.php* to your {laravelProjectDir}\config folder
- rename the file to *datatables.php*

Since the configuration is already as you need it (*case_insensitive => true*) there is no more to do. The configuration just does not seem to work when in vendor folder.

The last hint I needed to solve it, I found here: 
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/612

Edit - 13 Aug. 2017
A more elegant way to get vendor configuration files into your project is by using the corresponding artisan command:
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag="config"`

Answer (score 0):

Just create php file name "datatables.php" on config folder of laravel and paste below code. its working. Thanks

```
return [

    'search'          => [

        'smart'            => true,

        'case_insensitive' => true,

        'use_wildcards'    => false,
    ],

    'fractal'         => [
        'includes'   => 'include',

        'serializer' => 'League\Fractal\Serializer\DataArraySerializer',
    ],

    'script_template' => 'datatables::script',

    'index_column'    => 'DT_Row_Index',

    'namespace'       => [

        'base'  => 'DataTables',

        'model' => '',
    ],

    'pdf_generator'   => 'excel',

    'snappy'          => [

        'options'     => [
            'no-outline'    => true,
            'margin-left'   => '0',
            'margin-right'  => '0',
            'margin-top'    => '10mm',
            'margin-bottom' => '10mm',
        ],
        'orientation' => 'landscape',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a very late reply but running this command in your project root directory does the magic
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag="config"`